# Java class that starts a new thread in main class

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm trying to write a library for my users, and would like it to be as easy to use as possible. Right now, to use it, you have to start a new thread, and set a lot of variables to track, in your main class, however my users are not always experienced in Java, and threading might be too hard for some of my users.

So I want to move the entire threading into my class, and allow users to call a function, to start the thread.

Here is the thread I'm currently running in the main class:

```
int valueToAdd = 0;

DreamStatsTracker tracker = new DreamStatsTracker();

StartSessionResponse response = tracker.StartSession("ae-13s-90-11", "Abe");

System.out.println(response.getMessage());

System.out.println("Adding skill Herblore");

String message = tracker.AddSkill(response.getSessionId(), Skill.HERBLORE, "Abe");

Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {  
  while(true) {
    tracker.SetValueForSkill(response.getSessionId(), Skill.HERBLORE, valueToAdd);
  }
});
```

I would like to move that entire thing into the `DreamStatsTracker` class, and do something like this from the main class:

```
DreamStatsTracker tracker = new DreamStatsTracker();

tracker.AddSkill(Skill1, ValueForSkill1);

tracker.AddSkill(Skill2, ValueForSkill2);

tracker.Start();
```

This would start a new instance of the `DreamStatsTracker`, which would start a new thread, and track the values of the added skills continuously in the background, while the main class is running.

How would I approach this, and is it even possible?

Comment: So.. you wanna move the `new Thread` initialization into a DreamStatsTracker method called `Start()` ?

Comment: Something along those lines yeah. It would include a foreach loop in the Start method that runs the following code for each skill added:

tracker.AddSkill(response.getSessionId(), SkillName, "Username");

and then continiously tracks the data sent to those skills in the thread

Comment: So, what's the problem? Just move that thread creation and start into `tracker.start()` method and that's all.

Comment: Consider using a `ThreadFactory` that can be supplied by the client instead of calling `new Thread(...)`.  It will make your library significantly more attractive to sophisticated users and, assuming you make it optional, it will not burden novice users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved my issue, by hours of testing and trying.

This is what I did:

Tracker class:

```
Thread mainThread;

public DreamStatsTracker(){
    mainThread = new Thread(() -> {
        while(true){
            for (SkillAndValue skillAndValue : Skills) {
                try {
                    SetValueForSkill(this.SessionId, skillAndValue.getSkill(), skillAndValue.getValue());
                    System.out.println("Added value: " + skillAndValue.getValue());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

}

public void AddSkillAndValue(Skill Skill, Callable<Integer> function) throws Exception{
    Skills.add(new SkillAndValue(Skill, function));
}

public void Start(){
    for (SkillAndValue skillAndValue : Skills) {
        AddSkill(this.SessionId, skillAndValue.getSkill(), this.Username);
    }
    this.mainThread.start();
}
```

This is the main class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    DreamStatsTracker tracker = new DreamStatsTracker();

    tracker.StartNewSession("ae-13s-90-11", "Abe");

    tracker.AddSkillAndValue(Skill.HERBLORE, getRandomNumber());

    tracker.Start();

}

private static Callable<Integer> getRandomNumber(){
    return new Callable<Integer>(){
        public Integer call(){
            Random random = new Random();
            return random.nextInt(10000);
        }
    };
}
```